# Parametric sweep batch mode in Gnucap

Tags: simulation, spice

When doing simulations in Gnucap, batch mode, how can I do a parametric sweep? The `sweep` command works in interactive mode, but when done in batch mode with `.sweep` it enters interactive mode and I have to specify my simulation parameters every time I do a simulation.